# Does biting my nails or the inside of my lips break my fast?

Tags: sawm, ramadan

I have a bad habit of biting my nails and inside of my lips. Does this break my fast? How can I reduce this habit?

Answer (score 1):

Nail biting does not break one’s fast unless parts of the nails are swallowed deliberately.

Answer (score -2):

Nails aren't even food, no it doesn't break your fast. Reducing this habit however, keep your nails trimmed and short so there's nothing to bite. You can apply bitter-tasting nail polish to your nails (and yes the polish is fine and halal), tell the people around you to remind you to stop biting if they catch you doing it. Also, make sure to wash your hands, especially around the nail area frequently since your a nail biter. For the lip biting I had the same problem but controlled myself to stop.

Comment: Why are you guys voting down my answer I literally gave good advice

Comment: Thanks for the tips.